# How to update data through "UPDATE TABLE SET COL1 = %s WHERE COL2=%s", using mysql.connect, python

Tags: python, mysql

```
import mysql.connector as mc


USER = ''
PASSWORD = ''
HOST = ''
DATABASE = ''


mydb = mc.connect(user=USER, password=PASSWORD, host=HOST, database=DATABASE)
print(mydb.get_server_info())
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

### Let's just say "len(list_example_01) = len(list_example_02)"
### and "len(rows)" (SELECT column01_name FROM table_name WHERE DATE > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s') also same. 


data_example = []
for idz, i in enumerate(list_example_01):
    data_example.append((i, list_example_02[idz]))

sql = '''
    UPDATE table_name SET column01_name = %s WHERE column02_name = %s AND DATE > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')
'''

mycursor.executemany(sql, data_example)
mydb.commit()
```

I am a beginner to mysql and python. I try to update value01 into column01 WHERE column02_name = list_example02[idz].

Following just show what i try to make...... e.i:

| CPUNAME | IMG_PATH | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I5-11400 | http://bcd/~~ | 2021-04-30 15:00:00 |
| I5-10900 | http://abcd/~~ | 2021-04-30 15:00:00 |

more...

I have list.
list_example_02 = ["I5-11400", "I5-10900", "I5-10400", ... ]

I want to find the row (which has same "cpu name" in list).
And I want to update "IMG_PATH" column's value.

01_Run
UPDATE CPU_TABLE SET IMG_PATH = 'http://bcd/~~' WHERE CPUNAME = 'I5-11400' AND DATE > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')

02_Run
UPDATE CPU_TABLE SET IMG_PATH = 'http://abcd/~~' WHERE CPUNAME = 'I5-10900' AND DATE > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')

i try to make loop (01_RUN, 02_RUN, ...) with 2var (1 var is for searching, and choosing specific row, and other Var is for Value.)

But...... when i run script above, i met "error message"

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 75, in **call**
return bytes(self.params[index])
IndexError: tuple index out of range

As above written, Tuple has 2 element and there are 2 placeholder (%s) in preparedstatement. But I got error - Index out of range -.

This is the question which i have.

how to fix this?

"Thank you in advance"

Comment: Why is query in code different from query in text , and even different in the title.... Why 3 variants to 1 question ????

Comment: Query in text is just example. i just want to show "what i try to make".

Comment: As you see, i want to make some "loop" with "UPDATE SET" command on mysql. So i posted like this. Is there mistake i did? This is my first question. If some error on posting, please tell me...

Comment: i am guessing your dateformat %s is misstaken for a placeholder

Comment: Thx you for your comment, nbk.
 I tested "UPDATE CPU_TABLE SET IMG_PATH = 'https://abcd/~~' WHERE CPUNAME = 'I5-10900' AND DATE > DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')" on ubuntu cli. That "WHERE ... clause" work fine.

Comment: Ah, you did mean "Placeholder %s". Is there a way to fix ? If you can show me some code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @pacomini: My remark about the 3 variants is just that you should make the problem clear. So 1 variant is good enough, and far better than 3 different variants (trying) to explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to Format curdate() as it has already that format you want

Do that instead, and avouid the problem altogether with the %s and dateformat

```
UPDATE CPU_TABLE SET IMG_PATH = 'https://bcd/~~' WHERE CPUNAME = 'I5-11400' AND DATE > CURDATE();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

My question is "When using cursor.executemany(), i got error code.".
2 Var required in preparedstatement, So i make tuple with 2 Var.
But, I saw "Index Error : Tuple index out of range".

And, as i wrote above, WHERE Clause work fine. ("DATE column" set "type DATETIME")

Comment: execute many would use an array. so youtr code looks ok to me also show us the print of data example and remove the dataformat anyway

Comment: Thx for your comment. Ok. i will try to remove the dataformat.
P.S> other script used "executemany() with insert into command"  works fine.
But only this show Error msg...

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. After removing dataformat, my scripts work fine!